# How to search for quotation marks in LexisNexis?

Tags: database, escaping, full-text-search

How do I search in LexisNexis for a phrase surrounded by quotes?

Given that quotes are a search operator to force an exact phrase, I'm having trouble.

For example, search to find references to "this is a phrase" so that the result is "this is a phrase" enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Have you tried ""this is a phrase""?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately some search providers are quite limited in what they can do and from what I can tell there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in LexisNorris.

If such a feature were provided it would normally be done with escaping characters, e.g. `\"this is a phrase\"` or `""this is a phrase""`. But LexisNorris doesn't seem to provide such a thing: There is no mention of *escaping* or *literal* characters in their [search help page](https://www.lexisnexis.com/help/CU/Building_a_Search/Searches.htm).